# Convert NTP Short Format to Seconds

Tags: c, network-programming, ntp

I'm trying to convert the [RFC 5905 NTP Short Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905#page-12) to seconds. The NTP Short Format is a uint32_t with the first 16 bits being the seconds (i.e seconds = format >> 16) and the other 16 bits being the fraction of a second (i.e fraction = format & 0xFFFF). After converting I'd like the output as a double.

Comment: Be sure to account for endianness. The NTP format is big endian, while many machines (notably x86 and x64 processors) are little endian.

Comment: @FredLarson Thanks, this is already being taken care of:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `TS_short` being the uint32_t RFC 5905 NTP Short Format the following will convert it to seconds as a double:

```
double secs = (double)(TS_short >> 16) + (double)(TS_short & 0xFFFF) / (double)(1LL << 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is taken from a Google Group chat. I hope it helps:
Treat it as a 32-bit fraction with the binary point at the left,
multiply by a million, keep the integer part.

```
microsecs = ((unsigned long long) frac * 1000000) >> 32;
```

To round (can round up to 1000000),

```
microsecs = ((unsigned long long) frac * 1000000 + (1LL<<31)) >> 32;
```

Comment: What do you mean "with the binary point at the left"? The fraction itself is a uint16_t. So "frac" is just the fraction as a uint32_t?